# Как сделать длинное тире с помощью Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В HTML-разметке можно написать &ndash или &mdash.

Но если я, например, вывожу в input какой-нибудь текст с помощью js, то мнемоника не работает и воспринимается просто как набор символов:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('input').val('Москва - столица России');
});
```

Как в таком тексте, выводимом c помощью js, сделать длинное тире?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, обрати внимание, что текст вставляется в input, в нем мнемоники не работают. Нужно использовать просто символ длинного тире

Comment: @Grundy, как обычно не внимательна!) sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('input').val('Москва \u2013 столица России');
});
```

Comment: или напрямую символ: `—`

Comment: не обязательно его в отдельную строку выделять, можно даже так `'Москва \u2013 столица России'`

Answer (score 0):

В порядке извращения (ну, или если требуемая строка уже пришла откуда-то с закодированными html entities):

```
var s = 'Москва &mdash; столица России';
var d = document.createElement('div'); 
d.innerHTML = s; 
console.log(d.innerText); // Москва — столица России
```

Comment: это все из-за отсутствия встроенной функции _htmlDecode_